# Как можно очистить Replicated Map используя Hazelcast Management Center

Tags: map, hazelcast

Как можно очистить Replicated Map используя Hazelcast Management Center?
На UI не могу найти нужную кнопку.
В Console Management Center нет команд для Replicated Map.